# Converting .pcf font to .ttf font

Tags: fonts

I have some pretty old .pcf font files that we would like to convert to .ttf font. Is there any way of doing that?

I have been experimenting using fontforge, but not having much luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for all the help!
W

Comment: Before you do, are you sure you're allowed to and that whoever made it didn't already republish it as OpenType font for you to simply purchase? Which font is this? (Also I assume you googled how to do this, and found https://github.com/ali1234/bitmap2ttf -- does that not work?)

Comment: hey there, the .pcf font is custom made by one of my friends a long time ago and were trying import it into a program that will only accept .ttf. Thanks for the link but i think .pcf and bitmap formats are different?

Comment: nope, that's what they're supposed to be (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Compiled_Format) - thankfully OpenType *fully supports bitmap fonts*, so as long as the converter remembers to use an EBDT table for the data found in the pcf, you should be able to get a lossless conversion.

Comment: (note that you'll need fontforge as the conversion engine, but it's free over on https://fontforge.github.io)